# Is the Cloudflare proposed ODOH protocol a thing that could improve Bitcoin node privacy?

Tags: bitcoin-core, privacy

Recently Cloudflare [proposed](https://blog.cloudflare.com/oblivious-dns/) an improvement to the DNS over HTTPS protocol called ODOH (Oblivious DNS over HTTPS). It allows separating a DNS server into two parts: the resolver and the proxy that receives DNS requests from an end-user, thus avoiding leaking an IP address to the resolver and an actual query to the proxy server.

When running the Bitcoin node with the `onlynet=onion` parameter, one has to either leave DNS queries enabled (which could potentially reveal a user is running Bitcoin), either to disable the DNS queries completely (`dnsseed=0` and `dns=0`), and then to seed some good nodes with the `addnode=` parameter.  Both options aren't perfect.

Does (hypothetically) using the ODOH protocol for the initial node discovery make any sense from the privacy perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin running with `onlynet=onion` is **severely** insecure, nobody should ever be running the software in this mode. There is no sybil protection, it is completely feasible to operate an unlimited number of HS peers and prevent a node from ever connecting to one which will give them a true vision of network consensus. There is no cost to performing this attack whatsoever.

> one has to either leave DNS queries enabled (which could potentially reveal a user is running Bitcoin)

DNS queries can be proxied as well.

> Does (hypothetically) using the ODOH protocol for the initial node discovery make any sense from the privacy perspective?

I doubt it makes any meaningful difference, especially as seeding is typically only something which happens for initial startup of a node and likely never again. You're almost never going to be able to hide that you're running a Bitcoin node from your ISP, even by using a proxy the traffic patterns are very obviously Bitcoin.